Extending socket.io Socket interface with custom properties like user_id not recognized
I'm currently implementing authentication with socket.io in TypeScript for my project. When a user connects, I need to store their user_id on socket.user_id after verifying their JWT token in a middleware function.
However, the default Socket class from socket.io does not include a user_id property. To address this, I created a global.d.ts file in my types folder to extend the Socket interface as follows:
// global.d.ts
import { Socket as DefaultSocket } from 'socket.io';

declare module 'socket.io' {
    interface Socket extends DefaultSocket {
        user_id: string; 
    }
}

Despite VS Code's Intellisense recognizing the user_id property correctly, when I run yarn run dev, I encounter the error:
Property 'user_id' does not exist on type 'Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap, any>'.
My app.ts file:
    const io = new Server(server, {
        cors: {
            origin: "*",
            credentials: true,
        }
    });

    io.use(async (socket, next) => {
        try {
            const token = <string>socket.handshake.query.token;
            if (!token) return next(new Error("Not Authorized"));
            const { user_id }: any = jwt.verify(token, process.env.USER_SESSION_JWT||"");
            const user = await User.findOne({ user_id });
            if (!user) return next(new Error("Not Authorized"));
            socket.user_id = user.user_id;
            return next();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    })
    io.on(SocketEvents.CONNECT, socket=>{
        socket.join(socket.user_id);
        matchHandler(io, socket);
        chatHandler(io, socket);
        callMatchHandler(io, socket)
    })

Here is my package.json:
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon -r tsconfig-paths/register src/app.ts",
    "start": "node compiled/server/src/app.js",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.5",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.17",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.6",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.11",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cloudinary": "^2.2.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mongoose": "^8.4.4",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.4",
    "redis": "^4.6.14",
    "sharp": "^0.33.4",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.5.3"
  }
}

and my tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                               
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@shared/*": ["../../shared/*"]
    },                       
    "module": "commonjs",    
    "outDir": "compiled",                            
    "esModuleInterop": true,                            
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,           
    "strict": true,                                      
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 
  }
}

How can I correctly extend the Socket interface in TypeScript so that socket.user_id is recognized without errors during runtime?
